# How to organize multiple outputs inside a single Jekyll project?

Tags: jekyll, documentation-generation, jekyll-paginator

I use Jekyll to create documentation for software products. I have 30 + 
different products that have a common LIQUID template but different content. Every single product documentation has **its own table of content**.

For one project, everything is OK. I have a content folder as well as css/js folders. I run "jekyll serve" and publish a project.

The problem is that, I do not want to have 30 Jekyll projects stored one next to another with similar css, configs, js folders and will only differ in content part.

**The question is: how can I organize the internal structure so I have a 
single project with a common layout and 'x' different content folders inside the single project?**

Like:

_product1/

- some_subdir

  'topic.md'

_product2/

- some_subdir

  'topic.md'

If it's possible, how can I then manage the output? I need to publish product 1 and product 2 ... product 'x' separately.

Thank you for the assistance.

UPD: Here is the demo project on GitHub: https://github.com/plywoods/JekyllDocumentationDemo

Comment: In the most recent Jekyll release, they added collections https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/ however it doesn't work for me at the moment.

Comment: Collections were the first thing i had in mind. What is the problem - i use them for the same purpose.

Comment: @astark , thank you for replying. Inside my Jekyll project, I have created a folder that keeps all my collections. A single collection is one documentation project. Then in the config file, I indicated: collections_dir: folder_with_collections. In addition, I listed all my collections inside the Collections attribute of the config file. Now, I am trying to output any collection like: {% for item in site.collections %} – it doesn’t work for me.

Comment: Here is the discussion about where to declare  collections_dir: my_collections: either inside collections or outside.  collections_dir is a new feature relesed on JAN 2 2018 and it seems should be placed outside collections.  http://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-all-collections-inside-one-subdirectory-works/1034/5

Comment: @AndreyLangovoy Are products in any way related to each other?

Answer (score 4):

The way to have this content separation in Jekyll is through the use of [Collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).

Here is an example of a Jekyll website using Collections:
https://github.com/netponto/netponto.github.io

[image]

`_meetings`, `_members`, and `_sessions` are different collections and analogous to your `_product1`, `_product2`, etc.

---

[You can customize the output / how the URL is going to be in the `_config.yml`](https://github.com/netponto/netponto.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml#L14) of your Jekyll site. For example:

```
collections:
  meetings:
    output: true
    permalink: /reunioes/:path/
  sessions:
    output: true
    permalink: /sessoes/:path/
```

---

To display the items of a collection, for example the "sessions" collection, you do [something like this](https://github.com/netponto/netponto.github.io/blob/master/sessoes.html):

```
{% for session in site.sessions %}
  <p>{{ session.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

If you're having issues implementing the Collections, put together a reproducible example on GitHub, so that others can see what you've tried to do and point what's missing.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the assistance. Partially it works as you have described. However, there are many inconveniences (or I simply did not figure out yet).
1. The most recent release of Jekyll introduced the new feature that allows to keep all collections inside a single folder. To make Jekyll look for collections in that folder, I need to specify the following: collections_dir: folder_with_collections. Then I can’t make Jekyll display collections from that folder.
2.  I thought I could manage the parts I want to output right in the config file simply declaring output: true or output: false.

Comment: Instead, I need to modify the layout file and place a specific product_name in the liquid loop.
3. Additionally. I have many collections with different content. The project contains only one common _images folder. Should it contain images for all collections? Is it possible to have a separate _image folder for each collection?
4. I have a common layout - header and footer are the same for each collection/project content. However, the header should contain the name of each project I build. To make this working I need to modify layout again.

Comment: 5. To make search working for each separate collection, I need to modify layout again.

Comment: `code`
window.data = {
  {% for item in site.PROJECT_NAME %}
   {% if item.title %}
    {% unless item.excluded_in_search %}
     {% if added %},{% endif %}
     {% assign added = false %}

     "{{ item.url | slugify }}": {
      "id": "{{ item.url | slugify }}",
      "title": "{{ item.title | xml_escape }}",
      "category": "{{ collection.title | xml_escape }}",
      "url": " {{ item.url | xml_escape }}",
      "content": {{ item.content | strip_html | replace_regex: "[\s/\n]+"," " | strip | jsonify }}
     }

Comment: I am sorry abt the last one. I can't imagine how to format it correctly.

Comment: The main idea is that I need to make too much liquid layout modifications to output separate collections within a single layout. Why not simply declare output:true for required collection and output:false for those collections I want to skip in the output? Thank you.

Comment: @AndreyLangovoy Put together a reproducible example on GitHub, so that others can see what you've tried to do and point what's missing.

Comment: please find the demo project here: https://github.com/plywoods/JekyllDocumentationDemo

Comment: did you have a chance to look the project on GitHub ?